# Trouble with Humming

Tags: voice

I just started to practice singing, and some websites say humming can improve your singing. Others have said they can hum better than they sing, and higher notes come easier that way. However, the dead opposite seems to be true with me! Since I consider myself very bad at determining vocal pitch, I downloaded an app that can determine what notes you are hitting with the computer microphone. It said my range was from an E3 (lowest note) to an F5 (highest note). However, when I hum, my throat feels much more strain and my range becomes about an octave lower, an E3 to an F4#! When I hold my nose, no sound comes out, so I believe I am humming. However, my singing is NOT made easier for it! Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Humming should have the same vocal range as singing.  To find out what you're doing wrong, try feeling your adam's apple when you sing and when you hum. It should feel exactly the same, vibrationally speaking.  If it doesn't practice making it the same. Also become aware of any tension you feel in your throat between the back of your tongue and your adam's apple. The tension should be identical.